# Return all values in one = colum in SQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
$workspace = $_GET['workspace']; 
$location = $_GET['location']; 

$query="SELECT * FROM `offices` WHERE (`workspace` LIKE '%".$workspace."%') AND (`county` = '$location') AND (`active` = 'yes') LIMIT 0, 30 ";
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

The $location value is returned from a form on the previous page which has a list of 32 counties, numbered from 1-32. I want to have an option to select "All Counties" which will return a result which matches the other criteria in the query and any county. The list of counties is stored as a number from 1-32 in a column in the SQL table.

Apologies if asked recently but couldn't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: **WARNING** You're using a deprecated database API and are exploitable to SQL injections. Consider validating and sanitizing user input and using a more up to date database API.

Comment: Instead of forcing all the counties in the query, simply write a new condition where if location is 1-32 then you remove the county where clause

Comment: Also, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is (fairly) meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

```
$workspace = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['workspace'] ); 

$location = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['location'] ); 

$query="SELECT * FROM `offices`";

$conditions = array( "`active` = 'yes'" );

if( !empty( $workspace ) )
{
$conditions []= "`workspace` LIKE '%".$workspace."%'"
}

if( !empty( $location ) )
{
$conditions []= "(`county` = '$location')";
}

if( !empty( $conditions ) )
{
$query .= " WHERE " . implode( ' AND ', $conditions );
}

$query .= "LIMIT 0, 30 ";

$result=mysql_query($query);
```

It's a bit rough and ready, but that should do it

In your country list just have something like :

```
<select name="location">
<option id="0">All Countries</option>
<option id="1">...</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

i didn't quite catch your question. but the following will give you simple idea of what to do:

```
$locationCondition = "(`county` = '$location') AND ";
if ($location == "ALL") 
    $locationCondition = "";
$query="SELECT * FROM `offices` WHERE (`workspace` LIKE '%".$workspace."%') AND ".$locationCondition."(`active` = 'yes') LIMIT 0, 30 ";
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this will help i think

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `offices` WHERE (`workspace` LIKE '%".$workspace."%') AND (`county`    in ('$location')) AND (`active` = 'yes') LIMIT 0, 30 ";
```

Comment: Looks like it answers the direct question, but OP - really take notice of what other people are saying here too - you are building code that's open to SQL injection attacks, and that's not good!